# Meaning in context of "define __"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I read this conversation in a book once,

> A: Can you get me a wrench?

> B: Define wrench.

Is this "define wrench" a sarcastic tone, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying 'Define *something*' in response to a question or request is often sarcastic, implying that the questioner or requester has not supplied sufficient information about what is being asked about or asked for.

"Define 'wrench'" might mean 'What type and size?', or it might mean (at least in the UK) 'Did you mean a spanner?'

'Define...' might imply that the other person has only partially or superficially understood what they are talking about, or that the thing mentioned is open to multiple interpretations or is doubtful.

Person A: Is the project complete? Person B: Define 'complete'. Here person B might be suggesting that the project may be considered complete by some people, but not others.

Person A: Is JK Rowling a good writer? Person B: Define 'good'.

Person A: Do Gwyneth Paltrow's health products work? Person B: Define 'work'.